# Tkinter for loop counter

Tags: python, loops, user-interface, for-loop, tkinter

Python 2.7, Tkiner.
So basically I literally have a list which contains 10 items but i'd like to number each of these items so I created this code:

```
counter = 0

for i in range(10):
    digits = Label(new_window, text = counter + 1)
    shoes_label = Label(new_window, text = list_of_shoes[counter])
    counter = counter + 1
    digits.pack()
    shoes_label.pack()
new_window.mainloop()
```

This creates something like this:

```
  1
shoe_1
  2
shoe_2
  3
shoe_3
  4
shoe_4
  5
shoe_5
...etc..
```

And i'm looking for something like this:

```
1) Shoe_1
2) Shoe_2
3) Shoe_3
4) Shoe_4
5) Shoe_5
...etc...
```

Iv'e tried while loops, and creating 2 separate for loops, but neither seem to work, it's probably just me doing it incorrectly. It would be great if someone could help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to `pack()` each widget into a different edge of the window. That is doable with `pack()`, but you might want to switch to `grid()` for convenience:

```
for i in range(10):
    digits = Label(new_window, text=str(i+1))
    shoes_label = Label(new_window, text=list_of_shoes[i])
    digits.grid(row=i, column=0)
    shoes_label.grid(row=i, column=1)

new_window.mainloop()
```

Note that you can just use `i` instead of `counter`.

Comment: So I tried this but the window just seems to stop responding and then crash for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: No, I have no idea why. This code alone is perfectly fine, and you haven't provided an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that the errors you're seeing can be reproduced and investigated.

Comment: Previous code is basically just a title page which has a button on it. When I click on the button it opens up this new_window with the list_of_shoes which is defined. And the only things on this new_window is an image and the one for loop.

Comment: Ok so I kept playing around with your code and it seems the grid is somehow managing to crash the new window that's being created, odd.

Comment: `grid()` is quite popular, and works reliably. Something else you are doing (which you still haven't shown) is causing problems.

Comment: So placing the image that i mentioned earlier inside grid(row=0,column=0) and adding 1 onto grids in the for loop worked but because the image is so large its made column 0 very large and pushed column 1 far out and makes it look odd, any idea how i can fix that? Yes your code works like a charm, beautiful. I will accept your answer shortly

Comment: image_label = Label(new_window, image=the_image)
    image_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

Comment: @SirCodelot it will stop responding if you use both`grid` and `pack` for widgets that have a common parent.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a table, so `grid` is the best method to position your labels:

```
for counter, shoe in enumerate(list_of_shoes):
    Label(new_window, text=counter+1).grid(row=counter, column=0)
    Label(new_window, text=shoe).grid(row=counter, column=1)
```

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend chaining the geometry management onto the widget creation, because then you no longer have a reference to the original widget for later reconfiguration.